# Acumatica REST API - need info on API to show Account Inquiry / Customer Open Balances

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Want to know the Acumatica REST API to be used to get Account Inquiry / Customer Open Balances. If no such web services then how to extend end point using which modules of acumatica erp

Comment: Which screen are you trying to retrieve these information from?

Comment: Actully we are not sure from which screen to get this info and which REST API to be used to get this info. pls help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what information yo are looking for but maybe the following screens could contain it :

- Account Summary (GL401000)
- Account Detail (GL404000)
- Customer Summary (AR401000)
- Customer Detail (AR402000)

Though only one of these screen is already mapped in the Default endpoint of version 18.200.001 (Account Summary -> AccountSummaryInquiry)

If you need information from the other screen, you will need to either create a custom endpoint or extend the default one (I recommend extending).

Here is information on how to do both:

- Creating a new endpoint, it also contain information on how to add new entities in an endpoint : https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(14))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=709351cc-566a-47b3-b153-3a9fdd690ce0
- Extending an endpoint : https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(13))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=c450492e-06fe-4563-95c3-efa76975415b

I recommend that you take a look at the way the AccountSummaryInquiry entity is defined and follow the same way to create the other screens if this is what you do. I mean by that that you put the parameter of the inquiry in the top level entity and the fields of the grid in a detail type sub entity.

And in order to retrieve the information properly I recommend that you use a PUT request instead of a GET as this is the proper way to do so as mentioned in the following article:
https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(12))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=6340cff3-4732-4231-9e42-5d1e5e65b5dd